# Can sampling from a truncation of a random variable, rather than the original variable be more Blackwell-informative?

Tags: bayesian, inference, information-theory, truncation

Suppose you are interested in finding the mean of a random variable. You have some prior belief of it and before sampling 1 observation, you can decide whether to sample from the original random variable or from some truncation of it.

We can regard each of these two sampling procedures as signal structures or experiments in the sense of [Blackwell 1953](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2236332.pdf?casa_token=24OHkpYGOrQAAAAA:RUwYGqrcfFoppVsxFW15wtUNJt-wcVyTPOa6X20F5iWE9iFL3cDL5_ZgOqzBkZYTj2r1cvFv7iB2E1pPXqNedY8VghWLV7lZWSfUzrhebxjknR4KT5U). My question is, can sampling from the truncation be more informative than sampling from the original experiment?

The notion of "more informative" is also in the sense of Blackwell.

Question: Is it the case that no truncation will define an experiment that is Blackwell more informative than the experiment defined by the original random variable? (the truncation can be defined by any measurable set in the underlying sigma algebra).

Comment: Improve in terms of what?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to be explicit about it, clearly, I wasn't. I meant to ask if sampling from the truncation can be more informative than form the original random variable.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "sampling from the truncation"?  Are you truncating the *prior* distribution or the actual random variable whose distribution parameters are governed by the prior distribution?

Comment: Let me try with an example, suppose there is a random variable that distributes $F$, say with support in the reals ($F$ is unknown, but you have a prior of it $F_0$). Let $A$ be some measurable set in the reals. Then you have two options, one option is to get an observation of the distribution $F$. The other option is to get an observation from the distribution $F$ truncated to $A$. Can sampling from the truncation be more informative about $F$? If so, under what conditions?

Comment: If the truncation differs from the prior support, this is incorrect.

Comment: @Xi’an do you mind expanding on your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, truncating priors brings additional information into your model. By truncating prior distribution, you assume *a priori* that everything below (or above, depending if it is left- or right-truncation) has zero probability. After multiplying likelihood by prior, you are zeroing out the posterior in truncation region as well. You cannot make (negative) prior information stronger then this.

Consider an example, where you truncate prior from both sides, so that it has an $[a, b]$ range. By doing so you *force* the posterior to be something within the range *no matter what the data is*.